# Subreport not displayed in main Jasper Report ireport

Tags: ireport

i have simply generated 1 main report and 1 subreport and the problem is that when i preview the subreport it is displaying all the fields correctly but when i preview the main report  subreport fields are not displayed in the main report.

any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that, you have not specified any connection expression. Commonly used Connection expression is
`$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}`. 
 This instructs ireport to consider the data source of main report as sub report's too. Hope this helps.

Comment: yes you are right i haven't give the connection expression in my xml file but i give the dataSourceExpression tag in my xml and now its working...

Comment: i dont know  why connection express starts working today...:(